# AWS CDK Snapshot testing in Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

The [CDK Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/testing.html) describes how to do snapshot testing in Typescript. How would I go about doing the same thing in Python?

There doesn't seem to be a Python version of the cdk-asserts library and also there are very few documented examples anywhere of how to do cdk testing in python.

Answer (score 1):

AWS docs really sucks. They've created a [repo](https://github.com/cdklabs/aws-cdk-testing-examples) with some testing examples in Python, Java and Typescript. For snapshot testing, you must use some [pytest plugin for that](https://github.com/tophat/syrupy).

Using syrupy's snapshot fixture, you would test like:

```
def test_something(snapshot):
   s = cdk.Stack()
   stack = Construct(s, ...)
   template = assertions.Template.from_stack(stack)
   assert template.to_json() == snapshot
```

You must call: `pytest <test_file.py> --snapshot-update` 
Then a `__snapshot__` in current directory will be created with the snapshots defined.